# Staff can only edit only few selected fields other fields will be readonly but admin can edit all the fields

Tags: javascript, php, yii, dom-events

Staff user can only edit some selected input fields, remaining input fields will be *read-only*, but Admin can edit all the fields. I am a beginner in PHP and i am trying to do it for the last few days but in-vain.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if(($_POST['action']=='edit') || ($_POST['action2']=='edit')) { ?>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" class="form-horizontal" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <?php 
            $edit_id=$_POST['selector'];
            $N = count($edit_id);
            for($i=0; $i<$N; $i++) {
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".TSURPHU." WHERE id='$edit_id[$i]'");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" id="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div style="float:left">
                                <label><span class="tibetan">à½¨à½„à¼‹à¼</span>Â Receipt No:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 60% !important; color:#999999;" name="receipt_no[]" value="<?php echo $row['receipt_no']; ?>" readonly>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label><span class="tibetan">* à½Ÿà¾³à¼‹à½šà½ºà½¦à¼</span>Â Date: (yyyy-mm-dd)</label>
                                <input class="form-control" style="width: 20% !important;" type="text" readonly="readonly" name="subDate[]" value="<?php echo $row['subDate']; ?>" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label><span class="tibetan">* à½‘à½‘à¼‹à½‘à½˜à¼‹à½˜à½†à½¼à½‚à¼‹à½à½´à¼‹à½¡à½„à½¦à¼‹à½”à¼</span>Â Received with thanks from:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" style="width: 40% !important" type="text" name="name[]" id="name" value="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label><span class="tibetan">* à½à¼‹à½–à¾±à½„à¼‹à¼</span>Â Address:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" style="width: 40% !important" type="text" name="address[]" id="address" value="<?php echo $row['address'] ?>">
                        </div>
```

Here is the form:

[image]

I want only (Receive from thanks) and (Address) can edit by staff user, but (Receipt) and (date) will be *read-only*, these fields can edited by admin only.

Comment: How do you differentiate between an admin and a staff? Have you stored anything in session variable during log in time?

Comment: @ Rajdeep Paul ...thank you so much for user i have differentiate between an admin and staff will there user_level. Admin level = 5 where as staff level = 2..         <?php 
if($_SESSION['user_level'] >= 5) {
?>

Comment: Welcome! So does it solve your problem? Or you're facing other issues?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul . problem not solved. till now i just shared my code.

Comment: I have given an answer below, hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment,

> Admin level = 5 where as staff level = 2..

Assuming the fact that you have differentiated the admin and staff using `$_SESSION` i.e if an admin logs in, `$_SESSION['user_level']` would be `5` and if a staff logs in, `$_SESSION['user_level']` would be `2`, your code inside while loop would be like this:

```
// your code

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" id="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div style="float:left">
                <label> Receipt No:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 60% !important; color:#999999;" name="receipt_no[]" value="<?php echo $row['receipt_no']; ?>"<?php if($_SESSION['user_level'] == 2){ echo ' readonly="readonly"'; } ?>>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label> Date: (yyyy-mm-dd)</label>
                <input class="form-control" style="width: 20% !important;" type="text" name="subDate[]" value="<?php echo $row['subDate']; ?>"<?php if($_SESSION['user_level'] == 2){ echo ' readonly="readonly"'; } ?>>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Received with thanks from:</label>
            <input class="form-control" style="width: 40% !important" type="text" name="name[]" id="name" value="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Address:</label>
            <input class="form-control" style="width: 40% !important" type="text" name="address[]" id="address" value="<?php echo $row['address'] ?>">
        </div>
```

Comment: @Explorer You're welcome! Please *accept* the answer if it resolved your issue. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: clicked.check once please :)

Comment: @Explorer Thanks mate! :)